# Prove the Jordan lemma i.e. $\int e^{-R\sin{\theta}}< \pi/R$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, reference-request

In complex variables my instructor wrote on the board "Jordan's Lemma", and then, somewhat imprecisely,

$$\int e^{-R\sin{\theta}}< \pi/R \;\;\;\; \text{ e.g. } \int \frac{s \sin{x}}{x^2 + 2x + 2}.$$

I have searched for a reference for this result without success. I have many of the major books on linear algebra. Can anyone provide me a reference, or else provide the idea behind this?

Comment: You are missing the limits of integration for the first integral.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I know, that's how it was written. That's why it's confusing. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are concerned with this integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}}$$

Note that we may use the following inequality:

$$\sin{\theta} \ge \frac{2}{\pi} \theta$$

valid over this integration region.  Thus we have

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}} \le \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 R \, \theta/\pi} = \frac{\pi}{R} \left (1-e^{-R}\right ) \le \frac{\pi}{R}$$

Comment: I think that's the one! Thanks

Comment: Someone claimed that the Jordan lemma could be used to show that the contour integral of $$\frac{e^{iaz}}{1+z^2}\quad \text{for}\,\, a>0$$ over a large upper-semicircle goes to zero. Obviously we can do this by direct estimates, but I'm interested in how we could use the Jordan lemma here...